# Docker pull ubuntu no reply

Tags: docker

If I try:

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

I see only:

Using default tag: latest

Nothing more. It takes forever to load the ubuntu image. If I try it with debian it takes only a few sec.

I tryed it with ubuntu:14.04 as well, the same issue. Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I found out that it is only a problem with ubuntu and ubuntu:14.04. If I try to get ubuntu:15.04 it works fine.